# LaTeX: plotting function, formatting axis

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I've got some problems with plotting a function in a diagram with logarithmic axis:
I doesnt give me any errors, but I don't see a graph. Do I need to include any other package?

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{loglogaxis}
[xlabel={Temperatur [Grad]},ylabel={Zeit [h]},
xmin=10,xmax=100,
ymin=10,ymax=10000,
grid=both,
tick align=outside,
tickpos=left,
]
\addplot {10^(-4.59)*x^10.627};

\addplot
[only marks,color=blue,mark=*]
coordinates{
(75,105)
(57,370)};
\addplot
[only marks,color=blue,mark=x]
coordinates{
(40,1900)};

\end{loglogaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The next thing is, that I want the x-axis to have a logarithmic grid (for examples in steps of 10) but just one label at 10^2. I tried a lot, but nothing really worked out ...

Maybe you could help me?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: The plot does not show up because its domain (that is, the range over which it is evaluated) is outside the visible axis range. If you set `domain=10:100` and remove the `ymax` setting, you can see your graph. However, I think something's wrong with your equation: Over this x range, the graph's y values range from 1e6 to 1e16, so well outside the range of your data.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 2):

Remove `xmin/xmax, ymin/ymax` options and you'll get it.
[image]

Use `domain` instead if you want to restrict the plots.

Answer (score 2):

A bit of detective work shows that your function `10^(-4.59)*x^10.627` takes no values in your ordinate range, for x in [10,100]: it's an increasing function and its values at x=10 and x=100 are about 10^6 and 4.6*10^{16}, respectively, which both lie outside [10,1000].

Therefore, you must change the values passed to `xmin`, `xmas`, `ymin`, `ymax` in order to "see" that plot.

Regarding your second question, you can set the tick labels manually, using `xticklabels={<comma separated list>}` and `yticklabels={<comma separated list>}`.

**Edit**: [Jake's comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116353/latex-plotting-function-formatting-axis/116359#comment257908_116353) already says it all; I only saw it after posting this answer.

Comment: Thanks alot, first thing: stupid problem, i accidently switched the exponents. After that, the plot is visible.